# Setting HTML Style Using Javascript String Literal - Colon Breaks String Variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set the style on an HTML element before appending it to the page by passing the style tag through a variable in a JavaScript string literal.

So my code looks like this:

```
const STYLE = "font-weight: bold; color: crimson; background-color: red;"
const item = `<p class="text" style=${STYLE}>Some Text</p>`
const position = "beforeend";
list.insertAdjacentHTML(position, item);
```

When I run it though, the HTML on the page looks like this - the quotation mark on the style tag ends after the first colon. Is there any way to get the full string into the style tag?

```
<p class="text" style="font-weight:" bold; color: crimson; background-color: red;>Some Text</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const item = `<p class="text" style=${STYLE}>Some Text</p>
```

You should wrap ${STYLE} with ":

```
const item = `<p class="text" style="${STYLE}">Some Text</p>
```

---

Browsers for attributes values without " are adding them themselves and closing them before the first space in the string. That's why "font-weight:" was wrapped here:

```
style="font-weight:" bold; color: crimson; background-color: red;>
```